# Very slow application when running WITHOUT breakpoints

Tags: performance, vb6, breakpoints

Strange... I found some solutions like `Delete the .Suo File` but I don't have that in my `VB6` application... ;\

Let me explain the scenario:

-I insert a `RFID Card Tag` in front of my `RFID READER` then it fires an Event.
- When I remove the card, it also fires that same event.

IF I set a `breakpoint` in the first line of this event and hit F5 after it falls in the breakpoint then everything works GREAT !! But without the `Breakpoint` it take so long to finish... Like `30seconds` or even more...

I already tried to use `Sleep`, didn't work =\

Obs: I'm using `VirtualBox` with `WindowsXP` to run the `VB 6.0`. Also I tested in a notebook and it got even slower...

What could it be ?

Comment: if breakpoints speed things up, then start looking for operations which are timing out, but are timing out  in the internval that breakpoint forces the app to pause anyways.

Comment: Actually, the `breakpoint` is in the name of the event. So there is no code yet... Like `Private Sub MyEvent()` You know ?

Comment: The break point also lets events fire where a sleep just pauses the thread. Try replacing the sleep with a `DoEvents` and see if that makes a difference.